# Mapping to an Entity's array from single table?

Tags: php, doctrine

I have a schedule entity:

```
 class Schedule {

      protected $days;

 }
```

I would like "days" to be an array of **Schedule_Day** entities that look like this:

```
 class Schedule_Day {

      protected $start;
      protected $end;

 }
```

However, my database table looks like this:

```
 schedule_name
 sunday_start
 sunday_end
 monday_start
 monday_end
 etc.
```

How can I setup Doctrine to map this single row into the Schedule with the start and end times mapped to an array of Schedule_Day entities?

Comment: Not the answer you were looking for, but why are you storing information in the DB like that anyway?? Wouldn't it be better just to have "shedule_name, day_name(or id and reference to another table where days are stored), start, end"? Also from the object model you posted, I don't see how can you know which day it is in the Shedule_Day class